# Make PM2 run job only once every 10 minutes

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have the following .json configuration for a job that I need to run once every 10 minutes and then do nothing for the remaining time...

```
"name"        : "test.10minjob",
"cron_restart": "*/10 * * * *",
"autorestart" : false,
"exec_mode"   : "cluster",
"instances"   : 1,
```

If I run it like this, it will run once and never restart.

If I run it with autorestart set to true, it will restart every time the job exits (i.e. is done).

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Is "exec_mode" should not be the "cluster_mode" or "fork_mode"?

Comment: this seems correct according to the docs (https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#list-of-all-json-declaration-fields-avaibles). and for cron to work it has to be in cluster mode.

Comment: Best would be to use the real cron and setting `exec_mode` to `fork`. I can't find how cron is used in pm2 code.

Comment: autorestart should be true possibly

Comment: So your job once it finishes, doesn't exit automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this cron expression `0 0/10 * 1/1 * ? *`
I created it using this tool:

http://www.cronmaker.com

The expression looks very different from yours and also if i put yours into a cron parser it complains about an invalid expression.